# Can I resume after suspend by pressing a key on an external keyboard?

Tags: suspend, resume

Can I resume Ubuntu after suspend by shortcut from keyboard?

I have a docking station with thinkpad and an external monitor. My laptop is always closed, so I need to open it and close again to resume system, it's annoying.

Answer (score 1):

If the external keyboard is USB, you probably can, although it depends on your motherboard.

Check `/proc/acpi/wakeup` it shows all supported wakeup sources and their states. To toggle the state, simply echo the wakeupsource name back to the same file.

Example, to enable/disable wakeup from a usb device on my system, i do:

```
# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup |grep HC
EHC1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC   S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
# echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup 
# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup |grep HC
EHC1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC   S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
#
```

Comment: this command gives me 49 entries. How do I know what `EHC1`, `EHC2` or `XHC` is and what device this belongs to? Why can this command not simply say "External Samsung mouse" or "Built-in keyboard" instead?

Comment: another question, how do these entries relate to BIOS-settings? I can configure wake-on-lan or lid-close suspend behavior there - does `acpi` overwrite my bios? And a third question, how do you make these changes permanent?